# best practice to check if a collection has duplicate values?

Tags: laravel

what is the best practice to check if a collection has duplicate values. example:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$collection->isDuplicate() // false

$collection = collect([1, 2, 2, 4, 5]);
$collection->isDuplicate() // true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use
`$collection->duplicates()->isNotEmpty();` to check if there are duplicates.